# Coupled nonlinear ODE equations system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I am tying to solve the following coupled ODE equations system function of time:

\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
& \dot{\alpha}(t) = p \ \alpha(t)^{2}+ q \ \alpha(t) + r \ \beta(t) + s \\
& \dot{\beta}(t) =  u \ \beta(t) + v \ \alpha(t) \ \beta(t) +  w \ \alpha(t)
\end{aligned}
  \right.
\end{equation}

$p, q, r, s, u, v$ and $ w$ are constants.

Any help?

Comment: This is an interesting question. I would guess intuitively that there's a transformation that can de-couple the coefficients to get two Ricatti equations. But I don't know how to do it, so I may be way off base there.

Comment: @CadeReinberger : I tried that by I didn't find a way to solve the matricial system I got.

Comment: If $p=1,v=1$ the system is linearized by the substitutions $\alpha=-\frac{\dot\gamma}{\gamma}$, $\beta=\frac{\delta}{\gamma}$ for new independent variables $\gamma=\gamma(t),\delta=\delta(t)$ (the new system being $\ddot\gamma-q\dot\gamma+s\gamma+r\delta=0$, $u\delta(t)-w\dot\gamma-\dot\delta=0$). I am not sure the general case can be reduced to this (at least one among $p,v$ can be fixed to $1$, but not directly both I think)

Comment: @Giulio : yes that's correct, better may be for $v=p$ set $\alpha = -\frac{1}{p} \frac{\dot{\gamma}}{\gamma}$ and $\beta = \frac{\delta}{\gamma}$. But that does not hold for the general case